# Manipulating hidden files

Tags: gnome-terminal, hidden-files

How can I copy all hidden files/directories in the home directory into a separate directory from command line ? I wasn't able to find a lot of material concerning usage of hidden files .

Comment: recursivley or "flat" (meaning: also from subdirectories)?

Comment: recursively would do the job best, I'd say

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### What needs to be done

In principle not a complicated question, however, you need to take care of a few things:

- You need (as I understand) to copy hidden files/directories recursively
- You *will* run into name clashes (duplicate names, I tried)

The (python) script below takes care of both:

- It searches for files and directories recursively in given (source-) directory
- it copies found files and directories into a given (target) directory
- In case of duplicates, it renames them to `duplicate_1<filename>`, `duplicate_2<filename>` (or directory-) etc.

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import shutil
import sys
import os

directory = sys.argv[1]
target = sys.argv[2]

def handle(name):
    n = 1; name_orig = name
    while os.path.exists(target+"/"+name):
        name = "duplicate_"+str(n)+"_"+name_orig
        n = n+1
    return target+"/"+name

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for name in files:
        if name.startswith("."):
            subject = root+"/"+name
            newfile = handle(name)
            try:
                shutil.copyfile(subject, newfile)
            except:
                pass
    for dr in dirs:
        if dr.startswith("."):
            subject = root+"/"+dr
            newdir = handle(dr)
            try:
                shutil.copytree(subject, newdir)
            except:
                pass
```

#### How to use

Copy the script above into an empty file, save it as `search_hidden.py`. Run it with the source- and target directories as arguments:

```
python3 /path/to/search_hidden.py <source_directory> <target_directory>
```

Comment: Wow, this seems like a lot of work so thank you so much for your effort and also thank you for providing an explanation ! :)

Comment: @user43389 you're welcome!

Comment: @user43389 Edited the script to prevent it to break on temp files.

Comment: Just wondering why you would run into "name clashes"? Aren't all the names/paths unique in the source?

Comment: @w3d duplicate names, there are quite a few if you copy them from `~/` recursively (what OP asked for, see comment on the question).

Comment: I can understand duplicate basenames, but I assumed the same directory would be created in the target (yes, recursively), not one flat directory (if that is what is implied here) - is that not a requirement?

Comment: @w3d Why do you think so? The question seems not suggesting that.

Comment: @w3d It also seems unlikely, what would you do if a deeper hidden file has a superior visible directory? seems a strange policy to copy that one *including* the containing directory.

Comment: Well, I assumed - the question is not explicit in this respect. Copying into one flat directory is obviously highly likely to result in name clashes, and unless some directory structure is retained in the resulting filename (rather than simply dup1-, dup2-, etc.) then you've lost the original location/information (which I would have thought is less useful)?

Comment: @w3d I agree the question is not specific on this. At the same time, *any* policy to retain the directory structure is weird, since you could copy practically every, no *probably* every folder. The only solution I see is then to just copy the whole directory *except* visible *files*. That is however not in line with the question to copy *"hidden files/directories"*, implying not to copy the *visible* directories. Quite frankly, I have not been asking myself what is the purpose of the action, just to make it happen, and I think this is the most probable targeted action.

Answer (score 4):

If all the hidden files start with a dot (.), then you can do

```
cp .?* /path/to/directory
```

from the directory the hidden files are in.
This command says copy all the files starting with a dot (.?*) to the directory specified. '*' is a wildcard.

- `.?*` requires at least one character after the dot '.'